The Goldbach Conjecture | Decomposition to Large Numbers
I find some interesting patterns about the Goldbach Conjecture using statistic method, and want to share and discuss with you all.

Conjecture: $\forall\ N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists \ N'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall\ n \geq N$, the even number $2n$ can be expressed as the sum of two prime numbers $p_1$ and $p_2$, where $p_1, p_2 \geq N'$. Furthermore, as $N$ increases, the ratio $N' / N$ approaches 1. In other word, for the even number 2n, one can always find prime pairs around n !

Motivation: The Goldbach Conjecture states that every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two prime numbers. However, the prime numbers here might be too much. The smaller primes are needless as N increases.

Question: Has this been studied before? If so, where can I find the reference?

The crucial aspect of my conjecture is that for any even number 2n, one can always find prime pairs around n. The density of prime distribution appears to be higher than expected.
For example, since f(10000) = 9811, we can observe the decomposition of 2n into prime pairs:



2n
Decomposition
Lower Bound




2 × 10000
9931 + 10069
$9931\geq 9811$


2 × 10001
9941 + 10061
$9941\geq 9811$


2 × 10002
9967 + 10037
$9967\geq 9811$


2 × 10003
9967 + 10039
$9967\geq 9811$


2 × 10004
9941 + 10067
$9941\geq 9811$


...
...
...


2 × 10027
9811 + 10243
9811


...
...
...




Here is what I've tried:
Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of prime numbers, and denote
$$
f'(n) := \max\{\min(p_1, p_2) | 2n = p_1 + p_2, \exists p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{P}\},
$$
where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We can use $f'$ to find the lower bound $N'$.
That is, for a given $N$, we have a lower bound $f(N)$ such that for any integer $n>N$, the even number 2n can be decomposed into two primes greater than $f(N)$.
It is easy to see that:
$$f(n) = \min\{f'(k) | k \geq n\} = \min\{f(k) | k \geq n\}.$$
In practice, we might use the following formula, which holds when $M$ is large enough:
$$f(n) \approx \min\{f'(k) | M > k \geq n\}.$$
With this formula, I have plotted the following graphs:
Graph for function $f'$

Graph for function $f$

The ratio of $f(N)/N$

I guess it is related to prime distribution?
Thanks for your reading.

I don't understand the conjecture.  If, in  one instance, you can find some suitable $N'$, you are done, right?  All larger numbers will clearly work.  So...I think you are just conjecturing that there are at most finitely many counterexamples to a variant of Goldbach (you appear to insist on large primes only, which Goldbach does not).

@lulu How will all larger numbers work? You have to have $N' / N \to 1$ as $N \to \infty$, so $N'$ has to increase with $N$.

@BenSteffan  Ah, that is true, but I'm stuck at the point where, if you find $N'$ in even a single case, then you have proven that Goldbach has only finitely many counterexamples.  I guess we could go beyond that to say that, for sufficiently large even numbers, you can always require the two primes to be rather large...seems likely to be true, after all, maybe there are some heuristics to back that up.  Not sure.

For a huge even number $N$ , to find a representation with two primes $p,q$ near $N$ will in general be more difficult than to find just any representation. It is well possible that there are examples where only small primes $p$ work , even if Goldbach is true. Note that we search two dependent huge primes instead of just one. That this is far more difficult can be seen by considering that the largest known twin prime has about $400k$ digits , whereas the largest known prime has about $25$ millions.

@lulu
The conjecture is based on statistical patterns. I've verified the conjecture for cases below 15000, and the last graph clearly shows that the ratio N'/N approaches 1.
For example, f(10000) = 9811, which means that for all n > 10000, we can always find prime numbers p1, p2 ≥ 9811 such that n = p1 + p2.
To illustrate, here are a few examples: 2 × 10000 = 9931 + 10069; 2 × 10001 = 9941 + 10061, etc.

@Peter Good point, I've also considered that. And find that only small primes  work is not true. As can be seen in Figure 1, the minimal primes exhibit fluctuations, but within a limited range. Furthermore, in Figures 2 and 3, the minimal prime increases at a stable rate of approximately 1.
The crucial aspect of my conjecture is that for any even number 2n, one can always find prime pairs around n.

@lulu Sorry if my explanation on the conjecture was unclear. I am posting this conjecture not to find counterexamples, but rather to demonstrate that we need only search for primes near $\frac n2$, as illustrated in the table above.

If statistical evidence was sufficient to demonstrate anything, we would have long since decided that Goldbach was true and been done with it. There is a general principle called the "Law of small numbers" which says that sometimes a conjecture can appear true simply because the numbers in the cases tested are too small for counter-examples to arise. A famous example is the max number of regions a circle can be divided into by adding $n$ chords. The sequence starts at $1, 2, 4, 8, 16$ leading to an obvious conjecture, but the next value is $31$....

@PaulSinclair yes, you're right. I mean not to prove the Conjecture by statistic method, but provide insight for finding proofs by analyzing patterns in statistic. So I state a new Conjecture rather than a Proof-Fact.

It wasn't your post I was objecting to. It is clear enough in it that you are making a conjecture. But in the comments, you claim to "find" and to "demonstrate" things that you are only conjecturing. So I wanted to make sure you realized the limitations of what you have.

@PaulSinclair Thanks for pointing that out. It's always good to remain humble, especially when dealing with math.
I will share my codes and more statistical patterns after researching relevant references. Hopefully, this might allow us to focus more on the conjecture itself.

Your conjecture is probably right and already known and made. But since we have no formal proof of Goldbach, we have no proof of this apparantly STRONGER conjecture.
And to be honest I was hoping for better arguments.  Also it is not a question but rather a talk. I did not downvote though, since I love number theory and you did some effort.

Your conjecture is : we can always find 2 primes $p$ and $q$ near $n$, such that $p+q=2n$ ; near is not a mathematical word. can you replace this word with some more mathematical words. Do you consider that $10^{100} - 10001$ is near $10^{100}$ ?

Anyway , to make this really a conjecture we must make precise what "near $n$" actually means.

The last graph shows that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{f(N)}{N} = 1$. This is a very rough description for near $N$. I intend to find some constant to describe the specific rate of $f(N) - N$.
Now it seems that $\frac{f(N) - N}{N} \to 0$, so we might try examining $\frac{f(N) - N}{\sqrt{N}}$, $\frac{\ln(f(N) - N)}{\ln(N)}$, or other potential patterns. I'll share my code on GitHub if I make further progress.

When we try to estimate (with probabilist approach) in how many ways $Q_n$ $2n$ can be written as $p+q$, the small prime factors of $n$ are very useful to predict $Q_n$ ; if $n$ can be divided by $3$, if $p$ is a prime number (except $3$), we are sure that $2n-3$ is not a multiple of $3$, so it can be a prime number. And if $n$ cannot be divided by $3$, if $p$ is a prime number, $2n-p$ is often a multiple of $3$. In your example, you can check that the smallest prime factor for 10027 is 37 ;  you should consider numbers like $2(2357111317*...p_i -1)$
